# How to prevent users installing packages via pip

Tags: python, pip, user-management, home-directory

I wish to PREVENT users from running pip to install packages into their home directory.

I have a fairly large number students who have network mounted home directories and file and space quotas on their directories.

I want to be able to allow them access to the system python / anaconda, but to prevent them from using pip to install things themselves.  A huge amount of teaching time is wasted during unpicking things students have installed and unlocking their accounts because they've filled their home directory with pip-installed software.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can install pip with anaconda, so if they can use anaconda I don't think it will be easy blocking pip for them.. You could give them an environment.yaml which they install with conda, and then tell them not to install anything anymore afterwards?

Comment: Alas, asking them not to do it doesn't really help.  Lab demonstrators have wasted hours trying to find problems in a student's code only to discover a mutant and mangled versions of numpy used in preference to the system version. Home directories get backed up off-site, so unless you spend the time de-duplicating, tapes are littered with 100s of copies of the same things each of the desktops already had.

Comment: I have no experience with giving courses like such, but I think actually this is quite a bad idea. Giving students the power to change the shared environment can be really bad (for instance going from python2 to python3). One changed version will make everyone's code unexecutable...

Answer (score 3):

Nothing will be 100% effective. But here are some ideas...

- Use a global [configuration for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration) with an `index-url` purposefully wrong.
- Do not install *pip* or remove the executable bit.
- Use a proxy to block access to `pypi.org`.